# How to make army to help in survival mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if there was a way to make an army to fight with you in Minecraft 1.12.2 Java Survival Mode. I know dogs work but...I want something that looks like a real army, made of like soldiers, that fight anyone that attacks you or that you attack (kind of like dogs). I have tried making custom zombies and put them on my team. They work well except the problem is they only attack villagers, but I need them to attack enemy mobs. I have tried Iron Golems, but they don't follow you are hang around the villages mainly. They don't attack mobs that attack you or that you attack. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With constraints stated like that, I don't see any working solution short of hiring a bunch of people to act as your mercenary army on a multiplayer server.

Comment: Oh okay, I guess dogs are still the best for guarding you then?